# Eventbus event order

Tags: events, gwt, event-bus

Morning,

I'm using the `SimpleEvent` bus to send data from my centralized data reviver to the Widgets. This works really fine, I get one set of new Data form the server, the success method of the RPC call puts it on the Eventbus, each widget looks if the data is for it, if yes it 'displays' it, if not, it does nothing.There is only one data set per request and the widgets don't depend on other data being already sent.

Now I have a Tree widget. The child nodes of the Tree are created throw this data sets too, and this child nodes register itself to the Eventbus to revive the data for their child nodes. The data shall be received  in on rush (for performance reasons obv), so I will get multiple data sets which are put on the Eventbus at the 'same time' (in a for loop). I only control the order in which they are put there (first the root, then the data for the first child......). How does the Eventbus now proceeds the events?

- Does he wait till the first event is completed, so the first child of
  the tree already finished creation and register itself to the
  Eventbus, to revive the data to create it's child's.
- Does he handle them simultaneous, so a widget isn't even registered to the Eventbus.
- Does he mix up the order?!?!

Current solution approaches:

1. The best solution I can think of, is to only put new events on the
   Eventbus when the previous got completed. However I found a method
   which does so, or if it is the standard behavior of the Eventbus .
2. Fire a request processing finished event, when a event was processed by a widget. Yucks... this leads to a lot of additional code and causes big problems, when data is put on the Eventbus which doesn't belong to any widget....
3. Register a static variable which is set to true when the request got handled and the Eventbus waits this long till he puts the next request on the Eventbus (Quiet similar to two, but way worse coding style and the same problems)
4. All events are handled by the root tree element, which sends them upwards to the respective child's.

Which solution would you prefer and why?

Regards,
Stefan

PS: my favorite answer would be that 1. is the standard behavior of the Eventbus^^
PPS: The solution should also be working on when introducing Webworkers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `EventBus#fireEvent` is synchronous. It's by design. You can pass an event to the bus, have handlers possibly modify it, and when execution returns to your method you can check the event; this is used for `PlaceChangeRequestEvent` and its `setMessage` for instance.

FYI, if a handler throws an exception, it won't prevent other handlers from being executed. The `fireEvent` will then wrap the exceptions (plural; several handlers can throw) in an `UmbrellaException`.

Comment: thanks, so they are synchronous. that solves a lot of the problems I could have :)

Answer (score 3):

Although EventBus is a nice way of de-coupling parts of your application it doesn't mean it should be "overused".
I also think you should be careful not to circumvent the asynchronous behavior of your client-side code by introducing synchronous/blocking like behavior.

Javascript is single threaded so I don't think you can have two events at the same time. They will be executed one after the other. 
If you fire an event on the EventBus (i.e. [SimpleEventBus](http://www.google.com/codesearch#A1edwVHBClQ/user/src/com/google/web/bindery/event/shared/SimpleEventBus.java&type=cs&q=SimpleEventBus%20package%3ahttp://google-web-toolkit%5C.googlecode%5C.com)) it will just iterator through the list of attached handlers and execute them. If no handler is attached nothing happens.

I personally would prefer the 4th. approach especially if you plan to use a CellTree some time in the future. The Tree widget/CellTree widget handles the event and constructs its structure by traversing through the object.

Comment: couldn't that be a performance issue by fisrt iteration throw a list instead of directly accessing the object? btw, nett das noch jemand aus wien sich mit gwt beschäftigt^^^

Comment: It depends on how you implement it and how many level/hierarchies you have in your object. GWT's new `CellWidgets` (CellTree,etc) use normal Lists (DataProvider) to construct itself. Performance wise the biggest bottleneck is creating the DOM structure. The performance impact of traversing a list is neglect able. CellWidgets use setHTML instead of creating complex widgets (with a lot of DOM operations) which make them so fast. If the list is huge you can still implement lazy loading, etc. I think the 4. approach also makes the code simpler. 
Du bist auch aus Wien? dann sind wir schon mal 2;-)

Comment: cool, this would be a reason to finally switch from the 'old' gwt tree to tthe new CellTree... since it would change quiet a bit of my current logic, but thats only a problem concerning me. I'll leave the question open for a little while longer in case somebody has another approche suggestion :). Ja komme aus der nähe von wein. arbeite gerade and der 4. html lösung für unsere desktop guid ;). Gwt ist schon verdammt cool und auch wahnsinnig schnell. Macht mir echt spaß. btw kann man auf stackoverflow keine nachrichten senden?

Comment: @Stefan: I am using CellTree in several projects and I can only recommend it. Actually I recommend to use CellWidgets because they are really fast especially with huge amounts of data and have a good API. 

Man kann keine Nachrichten schicken, aber ich bin in dem GWT Stackoverflow Chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4916/gwt?highlights=true